# Clear combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a Combobox that I would like to clear whenever a checkbox is checked.
How would I go about doing that?

My combobox:

```
<ComboBox
   DisplayMemberPath="KommuneNavn"
   SelectedValuePath="KommuneNr"
   ItemsSource="{Binding KommuneNavne}"
   SelectedValue="{Binding kommuneNr, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
   Margin="3"
   IsEnabled="{Binding IsUdenlandskAdresse, Converter={StaticResource BooleanNotConverter}}"/>
```

My Checkbox that binds to a boolean property `IsUdenlandskAdresse` in my viewmodel:

```
<CheckBox Margin="3" IsChecked="{Binding IsUdenlandskAdresse, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

So when `IsUdenlandskadresse` is set to true, I would like the combobox to become blank.

Comment: Do you want to remove all items or un-select the selected item?

Comment: Just unselect the selected item, leaving the combobox blank :)

Comment: Instead of making it depend on the state of the checkbox (or the boolean it's bound to), I'd simply change the style based on the IsEnabled property (If I didn't miss anything, that's what the CheckBox does - it disables the ComboBox, right?). That way you could use the same behavior for all disabled ComboBoxes without having to rewrite that behavior.

Comment: Yes, the checkbox disables the combobox, but the value that was selected is still shown. I would like it to turn blank.

Comment: @BorisGrunwald Without losing / clearing it in your ViewModel I assume?

Comment: Yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood what you are trying to do correctly, you want the ComoBox to be blank (or at least look blank) when it is disabled. The simplest way to do this is to change the `Foreground` (The color used for Text) to `Transparent` when the ComboBox is disabled with a style. That way you won't need any code-behind, can reuse that behavior on other ComboBoxes and you don't lose the selection if it gets re-enabled.

```xaml
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Minimalistic Demo:

[image]

```
<ComboBox Height="Auto" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=cckEnabled, Path=IsChecked}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBoxItem>Entry 1</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Entry 2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Entry 3</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Entry 4</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>Entry 5</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
<CheckBox Name="cckEnabled" Content="Enabled"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clear your ComboBox (remove all **selectable** items from ItemsSource):

```cs
public bool IsUdenlandskAdresse
{
   get { return _isUdenLandskAdresse; }
   set 
   { 
     SetProperty(ref _isUdenLandskAdresse, value); 
     // this will clear your collection if value=true
     if(value)
       KommuneNave.Clear();
   }
}
```

If you want to unselect the SelectedItem:

```cs
public bool IsUdenlandskAdresse
{
   get { return _isUdenLandskAdresse; }
   set 
   { 
     SetProperty(ref _isUdenLandskAdresse, value); 
     // just set the SelectedItem BindingTarget to null
     if(value)
       kommunenr = null;
   }
}
```